# Is it possible to receive payments through credit/debit card into paypal personal account. ( Not Business Account )

Tags: paypal

Paypal allows to test payments using sandbox accounts. However, where I live on live, it says to upgrade it to business account. Is it possible to go live and get client ID and secret key?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you cannot create REST credentials for a personal account.

You should in fact upgrade it to a business account. There is no reason not to.

Comment: I've heard that its possible to get credentials by upgrading to premier account. But I don't see any option in my account of upgrading to premier account. (Canada). Do this vary from region to region?

Comment: Premier accounts are deprecated. Use a business one